# htaccess - redirecting all traffic to app.example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Im trying to redirect my app yet i have some problems.
I tried with:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://app.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
```

I would like to redirect all incoming traffic from:

```
app.example.com
www.app.example.com
http://app.example.com
https://www.app.example.com
to https://app.example.com
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://app.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

//this redirect all not existing routes to index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```